# Spring MVC with MongoDB - Filter records with FindAll function

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie in Java Spring MVC and MongoDB. Now I have one problem of querying results from database. I saw that in MongoDB repository has one function "findAll". I can get the result by that function then re-filter using for loop. But what if the database extend up to 1 million of records ?

I don't know whether it has a some parameters to put in the findAll function like "findAll(delegate function () {return a > b})".

Please guide me how to do so :).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for the same

```
Query searchComponentQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("userId").is(userdetail.getUser().getId()));
  List<Component> components = getMongoOps().find(searchComponentQuery, Component.class);
```

Thanks.